# Withdraw USD from PayPal without conversion to my home currency of EUR?

Tags: fees, paypal, withdrawal, european-union, eur-euro

Is there a possibility to withdraw USD from Paypal to my EU country (our currency is EUR) without converting from USD to EUR on Paypal's side (because of Paypal's high conversion fee)?

I have USD account in my country with USD Visa debit card. Will I be able to withdraw USD from my Paypal to my USD Visa debit card without converting to EUR (and then again back to USD)?

Answer (score 1):

I just tried doing that on my PP which is in the Netherlands, I have added a USD bank account (from my dutch bank) and they sent the verification amount in Euros, I called the bank and wonder why they didn't let me choose account currency they said it's not possible and if I cashout Dollars that I have in my PP (cause we usually do international business so we set it to dollars) it will be changed to Euros, So we decided to keep the dollars in account to pay our bills instead of getting ripped off by PayPal in xchange rates.

Comment: Paypal will appreciate this as they will get another up to 5 % of the amount you pay. However, I will probably do the same :)

Answer (score 1):

Look for EU banks that have US branches. Open an account there and look for the SWIFT code of your bank in US. Withdraw money using SWIFT US code.